# Spring boot Jasper Report : Java bean as data source

Tags: java, jasper-reports, javabeans

I have Java class :

```
public class TrainingExerciseDTO{

    private Integer id;

    private Integer trainingId;

    private String color;

    private Integer trainingOrder;

    private Boolean superset = false;

    private Integer exerciseId;

    private ExerciseDTO exercise;

    private Integer setCount;

    private List<TrainingExerciseRepetitionDTO> reps;
```

I need array of this class to serve me as a datasource in Jasper Report. My project is written using spring boot. So for every row i would need to list exercise and it's fields ( one of them is array of image urls), and also reps objects. One row of my report should look like this :

[image]

Every data on this picture is from this TrainingExerciseDTO object.

How can pass ArrayList to report from spring boot and also use it in Jaspersoft Studio to create .jrxml file ?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You don't know how to pass your data set to report?

Comment: Yes, and how to do that also in Jaspersoft studio to create .jrxml file

Comment: So you do know nothing about Jasper? I recommend you to find some tutorial. This site is for answering specific questions and yours is too broad.

Comment: I used Jasper with query as datasource which i can't use in this case. Can you recommend me some good tutorial regarding this ?

Comment: @user3364181 [JasperReports Ultimate Guide](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf) & [Sample Reference](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference.html)